# Fail to access a Windows drive from a live session

Tags: partitioning, windows, mount, files, find

I am attempting to use Ubuntu to rescue files from a Windows pc. I am using Ubuntu for the first time, so I am a complete novice. I am asking for assistance to find the files on the pc.

I have a Windows PC with 2 installed hard disks, 1 is partitioned and includes the C drive.

I am able to boot up the pc using Ubuntu on a USB stick. The PC will not boot without it as it asks for a boot device.

When in Ubuntu the only device shown in dash is the floppy drive.  In the bios drop down list the hard drive does not show up as a boot option.

In Terminal having written `sudo fdisk -l` I get the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda:31.9 GB, 31876710400 bytes......... 

Device    Boot Start  End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *    39232  62259199 31109984 c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Being a novice, I do not know how to mount the Windows partitions c, d and e to be able to see the files I want.

Using instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions
I typed in the Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /media/fat_partition
sudo mount -t vfat -o defaults,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=100,umask=000 /dev/sda1 /media/fat_partition
```

I get the message

```
mount: special device dev/sda1 does not exist.
```

I am following instructions parrot fashion, not understanding what I am doing so if anyone feels they have the answer to this newbie's question I would be grateful for simple steps.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? What did maybe help you? If not, what is the output of `dmesg | grep sda`?